# interpreting certain coefficients as coordinates

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By means of Pluecker coordinates, there is a $1-1$ mapping between all lines of $\mathbb{P}^3$ and a certain
quadratic hypersurface $\Pi$ of $\mathbb{P}^5$. Let $X$ be a curve of $\mathbb{P}^3$ and let $Y$ be the points of $\Pi$ that correspond to lines meeting $X$. Then $Y$ is a projective variety of codimension $1$ inside $\Pi$. Then Schafarevich-1970 writes at p.65:

> If we knew that in $\Pi$, as in $\mathbb{P}^n$, any subvariety of codimension $1$ is given by a single equation, then the coefficients of this equation (i.e. the equation of $Y$ in $\Pi$) could be taken as coordinates of $X$.

**Question:** In what sense would these coefficients be viewed as coordinates of $X$? Can this be demonstrated by an example, possibly involving a different variety of codimension $1$?